# How to resume after transition is paused in D3 version 3?

Tags: d3.js

I've this piece of **D3 version 3 code**. I've a list of countries, and this it used to rotate the globe to each country one after the other. At the end, I repeat it from begining.

I want to pause the rotation on `mouseover`, and `resume` it on `mouseout`. When I call `transition()` on `mouseout`, it acted weired.

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

```
function transition() {
  rotateGlobe = d3.transition()
    .duration(1250)
    .each("start", function() { /* Do something */ })
    .tween("rotate", tweenBehavior)
    .each("end", function() {
      // Insert code to reset all counters and start the from begining
      transition();
    });
}

canvas.on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    rotateGlobe.remove();
    console.log("Transition interrupted");
  }, 500);
})
.on("mouseout", function(event, d) {
 //What do I need to do here to resume the transition?
});
```